# Ruling on Making up missed prayer that was missed willingly because of not enough courage to take major ablution at night?

Tags: salat, sharia, husband-wife, salat-qada

Most of the newly married couples in the subcontinent of ours don't offer their Fajr prayer at masjid willingly on time! They make it up at the time of Zuhr prayer as 'Kada'(making up missed prayer). They involved in intercourse and they don't want to take their bath(major ablution) at the middle of the night out of feeling shy or may be for the fear of cold water or laziness,  I don’t know why they do so, but what they is that they willingly missed the Fajr prayer with the intention of making it up with the next prayer.
So my question is, If someone willingly miss any prayer, is there any ruling on making it up later on?

Answer (score -1):

It's not that ; you can't miss your prayers, The other guy is saying you can make them up ; that the prophet missed etc...

Look i think this was a time of war and they overslept.You can only make up when you forgot or overslept.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/111783/how-can-he-make-up-for-missed-prayers

If a person misses the prayer, one of two scenarios must apply:

1 –

He missed it for a reason, such as falling asleep or forgetting it. There is no sin on him in this case, but he has to make it up when he wakes up or remembers it.

It was narrated from Anas ibn Maalik (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever forgets a prayer, let him offer it as soon as he remembers, for there is no expiation for it other than that.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari (572) and Muslim (684); Muslim narrated an additional phrase: “or sleeps and misses it”.

Muslim also narrated (684): “If one of you sleeps and misses a prayer, or forgets it, let him offer the prayer when he remembers, for Allaah says ‘and perform As‑Salaah (Iqaamat‑as‑Salaah) for My remembrance’ [Ta-Ha 20:14].”

2 –

He missed the prayer with no excuse; rather he ignored it until the time for it ended, out of laziness and carelessness. This person is sinning according to the consensus of the Muslims, and has committed a major sin.

It is not valid for him to make it up according to the more correct of the two scholarly opinions, rather he has to repent and regret it, and resolve not to do that again, and he should do a lot of good deeds and offer a lot of voluntary prayers.

“Verily, As‑Salaah (the prayer) is enjoined on the believers at fixed hours”

[al-Nisa’ 4:103]

Jabir reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, between a man and idolatry and unbelief is abandoning the prayer".

Make wudu from your home and go to work ; Also you can't pray while sitting if you can stand ; just go in the parking ; next to your car & pray

If there are womens in work ; it's haram to look ; don't look but if you can't avoid ,then you should leave that job;maybe necessity can be an excuse ;you don't have any job, if you leave you might suffer famine etc...

Also jummuah ; but if you live arround 800 meters from mosque then it's not compulsory;The max distance the adhan can reach whitout speaker, just voice is the distance, i think it's arround 800 meters or less; you should pray duhr instead if live that far.

The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, you will never leave anything for the sake of Allah Almighty but that Allah will replace it with something better.”

So do what's required; So pray because if you leave it for sake of people , or boss then it's a sin.You should pray for the sake of Allah

and those who are ˹properly˺ observant of their prayers. 23:9

except those who pray,
Those who are constant in their prayer [70:22-23]

You can't just be arround missing your salah
don't go to the mosque , just pray in your house at least

Source: Musnad Aḥmad 22565

Put a halal ringtone ; incase you don't have one; instead of music when someone calls you , put a ringtone of birds ;go to playstore ,also playstore in the homepage may contain some haram stuff; the ads in the app you install also ; If you turn off your wifi and use apps ,You won't have the ads